# Ionic 3 - How to redirect roottab when opening app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, viewchild

I'm new in angular and ionic and I have a problem that pissed me off. I m sure the solution is simple but I after lot of searches and tries I don't find my solution.

I dev an app using Ionic 3 and use phonegap push plugin to handle apple notifications.
My app use the tabs template and when I receive a notification I want to open the 3rd tab instead of the default 1.

I tried the push method the setRoot method But nothing append except crash.
After that, to be sure to use the proper way I only try to open the app on the 3rd tab but nothing more, just crash. I appears that I have trouble with  @ViewChild.

tabs.ts

```
import { SettingsPage } from './../settings/settings';
import { NewsPage } from './../news/news';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { TableauDeBordPage } from '../tableau-de-bord/tableau-de-bord';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Tabs } from '../../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = TableauDeBordPage;
  tab3Root = NewsPage;
  tab4Root = AboutPage;
  tab5Root = SettingsPage;

  constructor() {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.tabRef.select(2);
  }
}
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Agenda" tabIcon="ios-calendar-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tableau de bord" tabIcon="ios-speedometer-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="News" tabIcon="ios-paper-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Tuiles" tabIcon="ios-grid-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Autre" tabIcon="ios-cog-outline"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

When I launch the app from xcode I only have crash and white screen.
When I launch the app from the browser(ionic serve) I got runtime error: cannot find module "." This append only if I use viewchild.

I m sur I don't use it in the proper way but, for me, I do the same as in the doc from Ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your `Error: Cannot find module "."`.

Edit

`import { Tabs } from '../../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd';`

to

`import { Tabs } from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: thanks a lot lot this works ! The error com from the auto import of the angular plugins with visual code studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

in app.component.html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    });
  }
}
```